# Button onclick is not working in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, button, onclick

This is my simple example i have try to execute on IE Browser. But in Chrome , Mozilla browsers this example works. But is not running on IE Browser. How to overcome this problem. Am really stuck with it. Help me on this. The example is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
function doAlert(){
alert("Alert is Working");
}
</script>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="doAlert()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onclick` attribute is supported by all the popular webrowser, including all versions of Internet Explorer (see [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) for more information). Plus, I would suggest using [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to create a sample of your code, in order to test it in all the web browser you mentionned to be sure nothing involve your machine or your parameters.

Comment: onclick is support zeratops. But the problem is it doesn't access the script i have

Comment: So the next step is to check for the console error in the developper console !

Comment: I didn't get any console error zeratops. When am click this button it has been clicked. But the javascript function is not triggered

Comment: I'm not sure if this would fix your issue, but the code lacks `head` section, and the script tag is placed incorrectly directly in `html`. IE has always been bad to fix erranous HTML, maybe moving the tag to `body` helps?